# How to auto-add files to git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm used to Qt Creator which works like this: when you add a file to the project, it's auto-added to git, so when you commit, you don't have to manually stage it. VS 2017's git integration doesn't seem to do that for me, however.

Can I get it to work the way I want?

Comment: How are you adding these files to the project?  Any files created by VS should be added automatically.  If you copy files into the project directory yourself, VS doesn't track how they were created.

Comment: @Jimmy: I'm using 2 ways to add files to the project. In the context menu of the project I go to Add and click either "New item" or "Existing item". When I do it this way, then click Commit, I get [this view](https://imgur.com/a/I2Oy9) where I have 2 options. Either I click "Commit all", which commits even untracked files such as gradientmap.psd, or I need to manually stage the desired files (in this case, `Source.cpp`), and click "Commit staged".

Comment: Ah I misread the part about staging.  I don't think VS stages changes automatically at any point.  Staging files when they're created would be a little silly as it would just be the empty file, yet it would give the impression that this file is going to be checked in.  A user would still need to remember to restage the file with any changes made, but it would be more confusing (IMO).

Comment: "Any files created by VS should be added automatically" - Nope, TortoiseGit shows the new files as untracked and I have to add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get it to work the way I want?

No, because the idea behind the staging area (index) is to prepare the next commit.

You can work on multiple subject at once, creating multiple new files.
Yet, not *all* those files should necessarily be part of the next commit: you can decide to make smaller commits, with only part of those files (or even patch within those files, even though [Visual Studio does not yet support patch staging](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/3656096-support-patch-adding-in-visual-studio-tools-for-gi))

When ready, you can easily select the files you want to stage.
See "[Save work with commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/commits?tabs=visual-studio#stage-your-changes)":

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/_img/vs-stage-files.gif]